# iOS ionic application doesn't receive FCM silent notifications

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have an Ionic 3 application which uses FCM for chat functionality. To handle FCM messaging I use cordova-plugin-fcm.

In my application I use only silent mode (without "notification" payload).

It works fine on Android. In iOS I received messages only if it sent with both "data" and "notification" payloads. If I try to use silent mode , messages aren't delivered at all.

For iOS I use FCM, not APN.

I send FCM messages as in the example of cordova-plugin-fcm.

```
{
  "data":{
    "param1":"value1",
    "param2":"value2"
  },
    "to":"/topics/topicExample",
    "priority":"high",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This stuff works differently on Android and iOS. You need to define the ios-specific apns.payload.aps object within the notification.

```
apns: {
  payload: {
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
     },
    "acme1" : "bar",
    "acme2" : 42
   }
}
```

You also need to allow remote background notifications in your plist. If you're using Xcode (the easiest),

1. In the Project Navigator, select your project.
2. In the editor, select your iOS app target.
3. Select the Capabilities tab.
4. Enable the Background Modes capability.
5. Enable the Remote notifications background mode.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1